# Using scope with LIKE and OR passing arguments to search in two different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

What would be the best way to go about doing a LIKE and OR passing an argument?

I've got an autocomplete field where users can type a postcode(number) or a suburb name(string) and good like to trigger a search in two different columns.

I'm doing the following at the moment, however it is not working:

```
scope :search_by_postcode, lambda { |q| where("postcode LIKE ? OR postcode_name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%").limit(10) }
```

What would be the way to go around it?

Comment: what is not working? What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth considering [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

Your scope would then look like this:

```
scope :first_ten_by_postcode_or_suburb_name, lambda { |q| where{postcode.matches(q) | suburb_name.matches("%#{q}%")}.limit(10) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up implementing a similar solution but using Arel:

    q = "#{params[:term]}%"
    t = Location.arel_table
    locations = Location.where(t[:postcode].matches(q).or(t[:postcode_name].matches(q))).limit(10)

Comment: @Digger Have you looked at the soulmate gem for you autocompletion itself? Might be worthwhile if you want your UI to be more responsive.